# Input Type Time Display Just Hour

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to allow pick just hours. I dont wanna display and allow miniutes. For example, User must pick 14.00,16.00 etc. I tried step attribute but ıt is still showing and allowing pick miniutes. How can user just pick full hours?

```
 <input class="form-control " type="time" step="3600" asp-for="StartTime2" />
```

[image]

Comment: just create 1 input with a type number and do your validation in method

Comment: Use a standard `select` element instead...?

Comment: you can't do that with the native `input[type="time"]` but alternatively you may see @Exception suggestion which should work for you.

Comment: Technically speaking `step="3600"` that you're doing is the right way, but unfortunately the support for `step` is patchy and buggy across browsers: you might be better off letting users select from a pre-existing list of hours, like what @RoryMcCrossan suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are three ways of doing what you want to achieve.

## 1) Select box

Use code similar to this:

```html
<select>
  <option value="0">00:00</option>
  <option value="1">01:00</option>
  <option value="2">02:00</option>
  <option value="3">03:00</option>
  <option value="4">04:00</option>
  <option value="5">05:00</option>
  <option value="6">06:00</option>
  <option value="7">07:00</option>
  <option value="8">08:00</option>
  <option value="9">09:00</option>
  <option value="10">10:00</option>
  <option value="11">11:00</option>
  <option value="12">12:00</option>
  <option value="13">13:00</option>
  <option value="14">14:00</option>
  <option value="15">15:00</option>
  <option value="16">16:00</option>
  <option value="17">17:00</option>
  <option value="18">18:00</option>
  <option value="19">19:00</option>
  <option value="20">20:00</option>
  <option value="21">21:00</option>
  <option value="22">22:00</option>
  <option value="23">23:00</option>
</select>
```

...which to be honest isn't the best!

## 2) Using JS to reset the minutes; Recommended

```js
function resetMin(e) {
  e.addEventListener("change", function() {
    e.value = e.value.split(":")[0] + ":00";
  });
}
resetMin(document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0]);
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="time" step="3600" asp-for="StartTime2" />
```

...which I recommend.

## 3) Having a number input box

```js
function resetMin(e) {
  e.addEventListener("change", function() {
    e.value = parseInt(e.value % 24);
  })
}
resetMin(document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0]);
```

```html
<input class="form-control " type="number" step="1" min="0" max="23" asp-for="StartTime2" />
```

This also does the trick but is not the best.

But I'm afraid you cannot make the browser receive a time without minutes more than what you have already done and you cannot prevent it with pure HTML as far as I know.

Comment: Second and third snippet is not helpful at all. OP wants to select hours from a dropdown.

Comment: Tip for the future (I already edited it): "Code" in the sense of a program's source code (not some numerical code, etc.) is an uncountable mass noun like "milk". You don't have _a_ code, you just have code, or a piece of code, or lines of code, or some code (and you will never have "codes", only code). Getting this right will make you instantly sound more professional.

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll heed it